# simulated robot in real environment?

Tags: ros, gazebo, pick-and-place

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to work with a simulated robot in real environment?
I want to do pick and place operation using a robot (for example PR2). It requires point cloud processing in PCl to detect objects and position them. However, the environment with specific objects are real. As I don't have a robot, is it possible to use simulated robot to do pick and place task of real objects?
Is it possible to generate a world in gazebo that resembles my real environment.  Than simulated robot can work with simulated world?
Anyone can please describe how to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202420/simulated-robot-in-real-environment?/) by [Ahyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19943/ahyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. you can use a pick and place application in simulation. You can also create an emulated environment in Gazebo. See: http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/Tutorials/The%20Pick%20and%20Place%20Autonomous%20Demo

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2015-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0